# Cargo website customize css for mobile only

Tags: css, customization, response-headers, responsive-images, cargo

My website looks good on desktop but on mobile version, the header is in a weird placement. How do i change the header font size and placement without it changing for desktop version.

Also my images look good on desktop but it's all jammed together on mobile version, how do I customize css to comtrol image size on mobile version only?

I tried to change the css but it changed the sizes of desktop version as well

Comment: google media queries

Comment: You can use @media queries here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries). Also iwhen asking pls provide your minimal but functionnal css and HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily determine css style for desktop and mobile differently with the `@media (min-width: 768px)`

Try the CSS for header:

```
/* Define styles for desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.header {
    /* Desktop styles */
    font-size: 24px; /* Example font size */
    /* Add any other desktop-specific styles */
  }
}

/* Define styles for mobile */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.header {
    /* Mobile styles */
    font-size: 16px; /* Example 
font size */
    /* Add any other mobile- specific styles */
  }
}
```

> Replace .header with the appropriate class or ID for your header element.

To Customizing Image Size for Mobile try:

```
/* Define styles for desktop */
.image {
  width: 200px; /* Example width */
  height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
  /* Add any other desktop-specific styles */
}

/* Define styles for mobile */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .image {
      width: 100px; /* Example width for mobile */
      /* Adjust as needed */
  }
}
```

> Replace .image with the appropriate class or selector for your image elements and give your desired width size.